# 2019 Community Moderator Election Results

Tags: discussion, election

Ask Ubuntu's [sixth moderator election](https://askubuntu.com/election/6) has come to a close, the votes have been tallied and the new moderator is:

[image: Byte Commander]

They'll be joining [the existing crew](https://askubuntu.com/users?tab=moderators) shortly—please thank them for volunteering, and share your assistance and advice with them as they learn the ropes!

Also, please join me in thanking Luis Alvarado who will be stepping down as moderator.

For details on how the voting played out, you can download the election results [here](https://askubuntu.com/election/6), or [view a summary report online](https://www.opavote.com/results/4509492899217408/0).

Comment: Congrats Byte! I'm sure we'll have you up the the elbows in work soon. Luis: Sorry to see you go, but I'm sure we'll still see you around here and there :)

Comment: Congratulations Byte, you will do an excellent job. Think positive.

Answer (score 36):

Thanks a lot to everyone who voted in the election and decided to put their trust in me. I'll do my best to live up to your expectations.

I'd also like to thank the other candidates who offered to volunteer as a moderator, especially Zanna who made a very close second place. I hope you all continue to contribute to Ask Ubuntu in your own ways and will participate again next time.

And of course, thanks to Luis for your job as a moderator so far and all the best for the future.

Comment: Welcome to the team, Byte!  :)

Comment: Congratulations. I voted for you the the last time and now, but in '16 that seemed to be too early. Most likely Zanna will win it next time ))

Comment: Hey thanks. No doubt you'll do an awesome job and meanwhile I'll enjoy the privilege of having zero obligations ;)

Comment: **Obligatory "With great power comes great responsibility" comment**  Joking.  Congrats, Byte ! Glad to see you get the top vote

Comment: Welcome to the team Byte!

Answer (score 21):

Congratulations @ByteCommander and welcome aboard!

I can only hope you won't regret it! >:)

And Goodbye Luis, and thanks for all the fish! You will be missed.

Comment: Goodbye Luis! All the best for the future!