# How to see election stats and who you voted for?

Tags: support

I want to see what percentage of votes each of candidates (for moderator) got and who was my 1st,2nd and 3rd choices. Is there way to do it?

Comment: I don't think there's any way to see your choices if you don't remember them.

Comment: Also see [Can I see my own votes after an election is closed?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/328530/can-i-see-my-own-votes-after-an-election-is-closed)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your own votes should still be visible when you visit the actual [election tab (third phase) on the election page](https://askubuntu.com/election/6?tab=election).

On the [election results meta post](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/18635/2019-community-moderator-election-results) you can find a link to this [online election tool's results page](https://www.opavote.com/results/4509492899217408/0). It provides a well visualized set of bar graphs that show you the standings after each stage, according to the used [Meek's STV](https://www.opavote.com/methods/single-transferable-vote#meek-stv) method.

You can also click on e.g. [text report](https://www.opavote.com/reports/4509492899217408/0?style=txt) to get a more precise tabular representation of the individual stages of the ballot counting and candidate elimination stages.

Alternatively, you can download the raw ballot data [from here](https://askubuntu.com/election/download-result/6) and evaluate them on your local machine. For that, you can e.g. use OpenSTV (`sudo apt install openstv`) with the downloaded ballot file and the settings you could find on the online results page.

> Method Options:
>
> ```
> Precision -- 6
> Threshold Formula -- Droop
> Dynamic Threshold -- Dynamic
> Fractional Threshold -- Whole
> Weak Tie Breaking -- Backward
> ```

Also see [How are moderator election votes counted, in plain English?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/77541/280883)

Answer (score 3):

**Checking the percentage of votes each of candidates**: Moderator election consists of multiple rounds. After the election ends you can download the data by either going to corresponding elections' result meta post or [election page](https://askubuntu.com/election/) and clicking on the elections' summary you want to know. The excerpt which would provide the link would be like this:

[image: Screenshot 1]

**To know your choices:** Go to  [election page](https://askubuntu.com/election/) and choose the election in which you voted. Click on Election tab. You choices would be listed on right side.

[image: Screenshot 2]
***<sup>Whitened choices for security purposes :-P</sup>***