# Present Moderator Elections, When the Election Closes, are the Results Immediate?

Tags: support, election

On this page https://askubuntu.com/election?cb=1 I see the message

```
Election closes in <x> hours.
```

So are the results immediate?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It may take 1-2 minutes to calculate the results and to be available on [OpaVote](https://www.opavote.com/) (formerly, OpenSTV) and 5-10 for Community Managers to post. For example, [2019 election](https://askubuntu.com/election/6) ended on May 21 '19 at 20:00, the [results](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/50380230#50380230) were available at 20:01 on OpaSTV and [Jon posted](https://meta.askubuntu.com/q/18635/816190) at 20:07.

#### Related posts:

- [When will we know the results of the recent elections for moderators?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/113746/468333)
- [There's an election going on. What's happening and how does it work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/135360/468333)
- [How are moderator election votes counted, in plain English?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/77541/468333)